# Power Bi - Power Automate Flow does not trigger when embedded in the SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, powerbi

I have added a Power Automate button into my Power Bi report and set a flow. When button is pressed it refreshes the report.

[image]

This works when I open the report in Power Bi workspace and it takes less than a minute, but when I try to do it with the same Power Bi report embedded in the SharePoint the button changes to Triggering but it never triggers the flow. 
[image]

Do I need to do something else to make it work?